# trouble matching gas used in transaction with difference in account balance

Tags: solidity, gas, truffle, gas-price

I've fired up my `testrpc` and deployed a simple HelloWorld contract using `truffle`. I send a simple transaction to my contract and I log my account balance before and after the transaction. Unfortunately, this does not add up to the gasUsed parameter I see in the transaction.

```
contract HelloWorld {

    uint public x;   

    function HelloWorld() {
        x = 5;
    }

    function set_x(uint _x) returns(uint x) {
        x = _x;
        return x;
    }

}
```

And my javascript

```
var HelloWorld = artifacts.require("./HelloWorld.sol");

module.exports = function(callback) {}

from_wei = web3._extend.utils.fromWei

var account1 = web3.eth.accounts[0]; 
var start_balance = web3.eth.getBalance(account1).toNumber();

HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance) {

    return instance.set_x(500)

}).then(function(tx) {

    console.log(tx)
    var new_balance = web3.eth.getBalance(account1).toNumber();

    console.log(start_balance + " initial balance");
    console.log(new_balance + " balance after transaction");
    console.log((start_balance - new_balance) + " difference");
    console.log(from_wei(start_balance - new_balance) + " difference (from_wei) ?");
    console.log(web3.eth.gasPrice.toNumber() + " gas price")

})
```

Outputs something like this:

```
{ tx: '0x1a2876b330618c75c7e264becbee75c491b47b5a17a0f9f9fe7fb124f0e93113',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash: '0x1a2876b330618c75c7e264becbee75c491b47b5a17a0f9f9fe7fb124f0e93113',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0xf30134cac3be167d6053a21953b87010ce7145ccb36775e76d38458dddfa81b9',
     blockNumber: 16,
     gasUsed: 21736,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 21736,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [] },
  logs: [] }
99939363900000000000 initial balance
99937190300000000000 balance after transaction
2173600000000000 difference
0.0021736 difference (from_wei) ?
20000000000 gas price
```

It looks like the difference in my account balance IS the same as the gas used, just a different magnitude. So I'm confused? Are these numbers expressed in wei? I thought I needed to multiply by the gas price to see how much the transaction would affect my account balance...? How can I get GasUsed to equal the difference in my account balance?

Comment: Check that TestRPC isn't using a gas price of `1`

Comment: No, its at the default gas price of 20000000000

Comment: The most likely explanation is that truffle is using a different gas price than the one that testrpc uses as default. The transaction object (not receipt: get it with `eth.getTransaction`) will show the actual gas price used

Comment: You're very likely running into floating point arithmetic errors. You should avoid `.toNumber()` at all cost.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure network as you wish in `truffle.js` file.

One of the parameters is `gasPrice` (Default is 100000000000)

[Documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration)

Comment: I believe this gasPrice is only used for contract deploys

Answer (score 3):

`testrpc` hardcodes the gas price of transactions to [`0x01`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/blob/master/lib/statemanager.js#L255), at least as of [`4727b40`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/commit/4727b407d5a43fb338452903aaf4f130314cc17a)

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Do you know why `web3.eth.gasPrice` returns  20000000000? And what magnitude is it expressed in? I can't get the difference in my account balance to be the same magnitude as the gas used...

Comment: @natsuki_1996 It's a mismatch between what the internal state manager returns vs what's actually passed into transactions when they're created.

I noted a similar discrepancy with `coinbase` / `miner` in a [PR](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/pull/286)

Comment: Missed the second half of that... Gas price might be denominated in eth/Mgas, though that doesn't seem to align with the results you obtained.  I'll have to dig through how transactions are processed in testrpc/its dependencies to give you a better answer

Comment: @natsuki_1996: I'm wondering if the issue might be around using `.toNumber()` on the `BigNumbers` you're pulling from web3.

I've used something like [this](https://github.com/DeviateFish/Lotto/blob/master/test/unit/debug_lottery_round.js#L551-L564) to accurately account for gas paid in tests on the testrpc (which should be agnostic of the actual gas price).  It might need some translation to the non-promisified version, but maybe give that a shot and see what you get?

Answer (score 0):

As stated above:

> truffle uses a different gasPrice than testRPC

If you really want to use `web3.eth.gasPrice` as a reference on your tests, while using testRPC, you can force its own gasPrice by running it with:

```
testrpc --g 100000000000
```