# How do I get configuration variables (such as gasPrice) in a truffle test?

Tags: truffle, truffle-config

I learned from [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/19057/1562) that truffle configures gasPrice in `truffle.js`, defaulting to 100000000000.

I'd like to use gasPrice in a test, without hardcoding the raw number.  **Is there any way to retrieve truffle's configuration variables?**

Comment: A kludgy way of retrieving gasPrice is `MyContract.class_defaults.gasPrice` where `MyContract` has been imported with `artifacts.require('MyContract')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
async () => {
  let result = await MyContract.function(payload);                  
  var gasPrice = web3.eth.getTransaction(result.tx).gasPrice.toNumber();
  // Executes in the VM but don't get mined to blockchain and report consumed gas.
  let gas = await MyContract.function.estimateGas(payload); 
  ...
}
```